# MySQL Subquery simple SELECT issue

Tags: mysql, subquery

Good day,

I have the following query.

```
SELECT `codeusage_id` FROM `panel_codeusage` 
WHERE `codeusage_exactdate` LIKE '2015-03%'
```

That gives 178 results.

But I want to know which codeusage is linked to active bookings.
So I wrote this subquery.

```
SELECT `codeusage_id` FROM `panel_codeusage` A
WHERE `codeusage_exactdate` LIKE '2015-03%' AND 
(SELECT `booking_cancel` FROM `panel_bookings` B
WHERE  A.`codeusage_link` = B.`booking_id` AND `booking_cancel` = 0)
```

This though does not give me any results.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have edited the query to look like :

```
SELECT `codeusage_id` FROM `panel_codeusage` A
WHERE `codeusage_exactdate` >= '2015-03-01' AND 
       codeusage_exactdate < '2015-04-01'
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM `panel_bookings` B
               WHERE  A.`codeusage_link` = B.`booking_id` AND
                     `booking_cancel` = 0
              );
```

Still to no avail.

When I run a smaller query directly at the bookings table to check if it has any results I get 168 results

```
SELECT * FROM `panel_bookings` WHERE `booking_code` != '' AND `booking_day` LIKE '2015-03%' AND `booking_cancel` = 0
```

So I am still doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a subquery that returns `0`, which MySQL interprets as false.  You need `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT `codeusage_id` FROM `panel_codeusage` A
WHERE `codeusage_exactdate` >= '2015-03-01' AND 
       codeusage_exactdate < '2015-04-01' AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM `panel_bookings` B
               WHERE  A.`codeusage_link` = B.`booking_id` AND
                     `booking_cancel` = 0
              );
```

In addition, don't use `LIKE` for dates.  `LIKE` is for strings, and MySQL has plenty of functions that work with dates.

Comment: Thanks I added this. No results though. :-(

Does the wrong approach to dates do any harm to the results?

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg  . . . Perhaps there are no matching fields.  If you like, you can set up a SQL Fiddle.